# Batch replacing text within .xml files within a zip archive through powershell

Tags: c, excel, powershell, zip, batch-rename

I've posted this question before, yet was not able to find a suitable solution for my problem, hence I have been testing some more myself and have some new findings and theories as to why It might not work as intended. I hope a respectable time has passed for me to bump my question with new info attached.

I am for quite a while, in my free time, tackling a script that can batch replace external link addresses in multiple excel files within script folder. I have learned, that you can't change external links via usual powershell to excel interaction, as these values are forced to read-only. However, there is a clever way to bypass that by converting the Excel file to a .zip archive and read/change the files inside and then rename it back to excel format.

Through learning and digging around the web, I have compiled this script function that should create a backup, rename to archive and then replace desired text within, renaming the file backwards afterwards.

```
   function Update-ExcelLinks($xlsxFile, $oldText, $newText) {
    # Build BAK file name
    $bakFile =  $xlsxFile -ireplace [regex]::Escape(".xlsb"), ".bak"

    # Build ZIP file name
    $zipFile =  $xlsxFile -ireplace [regex]::Escape(".xlsb"), ".zip"

    # Create temporary folder
    $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath();
    [string] $guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid();
    $tempFolder = Join-Path $parent $guid;
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $tempFolder;

    # Uncomment the next line to create backup before processing XLSX file
    # Copy-Item $xlsxFile $bakFile

    # Rename file to ZIP
    Rename-Item -Path $xlsxFile -NewName $zipFile

    # Not using Expand-Archive because it changes the ZIP format
    C:\7z\7za.exe x "$zipFile" -o"$tempFolder"

    # Replace old text with new text
    $fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempFolder -Recurse -Force -Include *.xml,*.bin.rels
    foreach ($file in $fileNames)
    {
        (Get-Content -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $file.PSPath) |
        Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $oldText, $newText } |
        Set-Content $file.PSPath
    }

    # Changing working folder because 7Zip option -w doesn't work
    Set-Location -Path $tempFolder

    # Not using Compress-Archive because it changes the ZIP format
    C:\7z\7za.exe u -r "$zipFile" *.*

    # Rename file back to XLSB
    Rename-Item -Path $zipFile -NewName $xlsxFile
}
```

So far, I am able to find the desired file, rename it to .zip, extract it to a temporary folder, and according to the powershell window prompts, it updates the archive with new files. Afterwards I am left with the .zip file without any desired changes inside. The files that are responsible for external links data in the excel files are located at
 `wk33\Gross Qty_wk33.zip\xl\externalLinks\_rels`
and are presented in the form of files named  `externalLink1.bin.rels`  and numbered onwards.

These files are essentially identical to a .xml file and are opened with either Notepad or Internet explorer through windows and contain the following:
[image: Example of externalLink1.bin.rels]

The aim of my script is to rename the week number within "Target=" parameters from last week to current (For example wk32 to wk33). The thing is that no changes happen even though no errors are displayed, and 7zip indicates that files are packed into the zip successfully.

I have tested what happens, If I unpack the .bin.rels file and change the week number inside manually through notepad and repeat the intended script process and I can confirm that it works. When I open the file the link is correctly updated.

The last 4 steps seem to be not working as intended, even though they are correct as far as I am aware. The changes are not made and the file is not consecutively renamed back to its original .xlsb extension.

Here is the output of my powershell window upon trying to execute the function:
[image: Powershell output]

I've been trying for several weeks to make it work, but nothing substantial can be changed as it seems. I would appreciate any additional insights or alternatives to my code to achieve the same task.

EDIT: The function is intended to be called upon from within the working directory, so it is supposed to be used as `Update-ExcelLinks 'Gross Qty_wk33.xlsb' 'wk32' 'wk33'` Although I have tried calling the file via its full path as `Update-ExcelLinks 'C:\Test\Gross Qty_wk33.xlsb' 'wk32' 'wk33'`

Comment: Please show us (as formatted TEXT) how you are calling that function. Especially, show us the format of parameter `$oldText`

Comment: The function is intended to be called upon from within the working directory, so it is supposed to be used as `Update-ExcelLinks 'Gross Qty_wk33.xlsb' 'wk32' 'wk33'` Although I have tried calling the file via its full path as well.

Comment: Instead of `$file.PSPath`, use `$file.FullName` in the `foreach ($file in $fileNames){..}` loop. `PSPath` prefixes the file's path with `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`

Comment: Thank you Theo! This actually made some progress. With your suggestion, 7zip successfuly unpacks the file into a folder with a similar name, however it seems that no further action is taken as the files are not altered in any way and are not packed back into a zip to be renamed into .xlsb format again. Guess Ill have to investigate a little more.